# Unable to import gdal in Python

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu

In ubuntu 16.04 I cannot import gdal in Python. My code starts with:

```
from osgeos import gdal
```

but I got error:

```
    File "ccomt.py", line 1, in <module>
from osgeo import gdal
File "/home/neptun/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo /__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/neptun/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description) 
ImportError: /home/neptun/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: VSISupportsSparseFiles
```

Does anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, the problem was in the libgdal version. It was downgraded from version  2.2.1-2 to version 2.1.4-2 when installing rasterio 0.36.0-py27_0 package. Reinstalling libgdal solved the problem.

```
conda remove libgdal
conda install -c conda-forge libgdal
```